# Angular: in Link, $watch(ctrl.value) does not work but $watch(function(){return ctrl.value}) does. why?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have been reading other people's answers as to how to use $watch properly in AngularJS (1.4) but I still don't get why my code does not work.  I don't understand how to watch a model value from within the directive's link function. Setting `scope.$watch(controller.value)` is only triggered before the value is bound to the controller (value still undefined), and later it is not triggered when the value changes.  On the other hand, `scope.$watch(function(){return controller.value})` works.  Why is that?

In my example, I have an age value on the controller `userCtrl`. I want to add class `btn-primary` or `btn-success` to a button based on the value of `controller.age`: below is the directive:

```
app.directive('myDirective',function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    templateUrl:'my-directive.html',
    bindToController: true,
    controller: 'userController',
    controllerAs: 'userCtrl',
    scope: {user:'='}, //example: {name:'John',age:9}
    link: function(scope,element,attrs){
      var vm = scope.userCtrl;
      var el_button = element.find('button');

      //WHY IS $WATCH NOT GETTING CALLED WHEN THE AGE CHANGES?
      //if we change vm.user.age to function(){return vm.user.age} things work
      //but why is that any different?
      scope.$watch(vm.user.age,function(newVal,oldVal){
        console.log('age has changed to ' + newVal);
        if(newVal > 9){
          el_button.removeClass('btn-primary');
          el_button.addClass('btn-success');
        }else{
          el_button.removeClass('btn-success');
          el_button.addClass('btn-primary');
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Demo on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/nFjiCzVhVJkUGY5AEM1C?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the value returned by `vm.user.age` at that point of time is considered as expression (or property here) to be evaluated against scope. If at that point of time say value is `12` then it will set a watch on property `12` on the scope, which is obviously not what you expect.

You should give either a string representation (`scope.$watch('userCtrl.user.age', function(newVal...`) of the expression that can be evaluated against the scope or function that returns the value. When you provide `userCtrl.user.age` to be watched, angular will wrap the expression in a [getter function](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/rootScope.js#L367) with the help of `$parse service`, to say something like (just as example the getter function will be more complicated to tackle null checks etc..):

```
function(){
  return $scope.userCtrl.user.age;
}
```

and that will be evaluated during the digest cycle for change detection. So providing a getter function yourself does not do any harm as well.

Comment: Thanks. Why does `$watch('userCtrl.user.age'...` work but `$watch('vm.user.age'...` not work even though I set `vm = scope.userCtrl` earlier in the link function?  Also, `$watch($parse('vm.user.age')...` does not work but `$watch($parse('userCtrl.user.age')...` works.  It's as if `vm = scope.userCtrl` was skipped.

Comment: `vm` is a mere variable, not a property on the scope. Basically you are just assigning value of  userCtrl reference to a variable.

Comment: Interesting.  So `scope.$watch` cannot watch local variables, only properties within the scope object itself? Do you have any opinion as to whether `$watch('userCtrl.user.age'...`, `$watch($parse('userCtrl.user.age'...`, or `$watch(function(){return vm.user.age}...`, should be used? Does it matter to performance? does it depend on what is being watched?

Comment: For the first question answer is it can watch anything (any valid angular expression), but any specific property values will be evaluated against scope. I have explained it i believe it my answer as well. Also why would you ever need to do `$watch($parse('userCtrl.user.age'` ? watch already uses parse service right? In terms of performance the way yuo have originally would be slightly better since angular does not have to create an expression for parser (Which is any ways one-time though).